# How to create a pivot table

Tags: mysql

I need to create a pivot table using only two columns, home team number and away team number.

This is the full table:

[image]

But i need to combine these two into a single query:
[image]
[image]

The resulting table should be 32 records. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a union. If you want to keep track of the origin for each, you can add a constant column

```
Select c1 as x, c2 as y, 1 as origin from...
UNION all
Select c3 as x, c4 as y, 2 as origin from...
```